# Adding additional information when rendering a form in Play! 2.0.2

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm adding more information to a user model through a LinkedIn API, and all this code is handled in a controller. When the information is added to the model, I re-render the form (of User class) in a new view. Is there any way to attach additional information to this form (built into Play!), to display which fields have been updated by the API-call?

Use case:

1. User enters view/edit profile page
2. User clicks "import information from LinkedIn"
3. An API-call is made to the LinkedIn API - the user is then returned to a specific controller (called Social) which handles the JSON to JAVA conversion of data, and binds the new data to the user model, and stores the updated model in the database.
4. The controller then redirects the user to the index() controller which renders the view/edit profile view again. (now I'd like to add the functionality that the user can see which of the fields on his profile were modified due to the API-call).

For instance, something similar to `form.errrors()` (called form.info() or something). If this isn't possible, then is it any way to gain access to the FieldElements, and maybe add something to them?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't clearly see the problem.

When the controller redirects the user to its profile page, you just have to populate the form with the data from the database.

Something like that:

```
public static Result profile(String userId) {
    Form<User> userForm = form(User.class);

    User user = User.findById(userId); // data have been set in the database
    if (user != null) {
         userForm = userForm.fill(user);
    }

    return redirect(your.view.render(userForm));
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with rendering the view - the problem is with rendering the view (and form) showing which (probaly not all) of the fields were changed by the API-call. For instace: First name and Last Name might be changed, but not E-mail and adress etc.), we want to display this in the view somehow.

Comment: ah ok, so you'll have to store this info somehow. Maybe using the `flash()` scope (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaSessionFlash).

Comment: Sure, that could work! Is there any way to bind a flash-message to an input-field?

Comment: Our initial idea was to add infos to the FieldElements of each changed input element in the form, do you know if it's possible to access the FieldElements for an input in any way through the controller?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. Another option could be to extend the `Form` class, in order to add a list of modified fields.

Comment: Yeah, we ended up looking at that possibility as well. Decided to just try to do everything through AJAX - I'll post another answer if I get it to work! Thanks tho :-)